# My function isn't being run, but when I run the code outside of the function it works

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a personal adventure game project and I can't seem to run this code inside a function,

```
current_room = "South"

def go_to_room():
    if "go" in main_input:
        if "north" in main_input:
            current_room = "North"

while True:
    main_input = input(str())
    go_to_room(main_input)
    print("You are in the " + current_room + " room.")
```

When I run it and type "go north" it returns

```
You are in the South room
```

But if I write the code like this,

```
current_room = "South"

while True:
    main_input = input(str())

if "go" in main_input:
    if "north" in main_input:
        current_room = "North"

print("You are in the " + current_room + " room.")
```

it works perfectly.

So could someone please help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need declare current room as global in your function.

Comment: You never do anything with your function, why do you expect it to have any effect?

Comment: you need to call go_to_room() after you received an input.

Comment: What's the purpose of `str()` in `input(str())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is scope. `main_input` is only changed in the scope of `go_to_room` so the value would remain the same outside the function. Also the function is never called, you just defined it. In this case I would recommend passing a parameter into the function to make it work.

```
current_room = "South"

def go_to_room(room):
    if "go" in room:
        if "north" in room:
            return "North"

while True:
    main_input = input("Room: ")
    current_room = go_to_room(main_input)
    print("You are in the " + current_room + " room.")
```

Comment: While I agree with your function, the fact that `main_input` is never defined locally in the function doesn't matter, you can reference global variables inside functions

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I meant the variable would only change in the scope of the function. I guess I worded it incorrectly in my answer.

Comment: Right but that variable is never changed, it is `current_room` that is assigned to

Answer (score 0):

you have to call the function.

```
while True:
    main_input = input(str())
    go_to_room()
    print("You are in the " + current_room + " room.")
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm dumb, forgot to add it. Calling it doesn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write something like that:

```
current_room = "South"

def go_to_room(user_input):
    if "go" in user_input:
        if "north" in user_input:
            global current_room
            current_room = "North"

while True:
    main_input = input()
    go_to_room(main_input)
    print("You are in the " + current_room + " room.")
```

Comment: You're calling `go_to_room()` with an extra argument.

Comment: @Barmar, sorry, fixed

Answer (score 0):

in part one of your code you didn't call the function `go_to_room()` . so while you run this code you remain in the while loop so that is why you are getting output as

`You are in the South room`

in second part of your code, you have checked that is `given_input` is either one of `go' and`north` .

if this found to be true then only value of `current_room` changed to `North`. and you will get the output accordingly.